# How to test payment using Nochex Payment gateway in Alibaba B2B trader script?

Tags: testing, payment-gateway

I have problem in Nochex payment gateway with test payment in teswting mode.

I have set following details but not working.

```
      echo '<form action="https://www.nochex.com/nochex.dll/checkout" name="form1" id="frm1" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="email" value="'.$rowsettings['nochex'].'">';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'.$rowsettings['goldmemberfee'].'">';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="ordernumber" value="'.$_SESSION['SellerID'].'">';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="description" value="Gold Member Update for '.$_SESSION['BusinessEmail'].'">'; 
            echo '<input type="hidden" name ="test_transaction" value="100">';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name ="test_success_url" value= "successurl">';                  
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='returnurl' value='".$rowsettings['url']."/goldmember.php?ncid=".$_SESSION['SellerID']."'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='cancelurl' value='".$rowsettings['url']."/fail.php'>";
            echo ".";
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the old version of the Nochex Checkout, it'll still work, but isn't best practice. This document will show you how to upgrade to the new Payments Page system:

https://esupport.nochex.com/index.php?_m=downloads&_a=viewdownload&downloaditemid=4&nav=0,12

It's basically a case of changing the address that the form posts to and the names of some of the variables.

Your new form should look like this:

```
    echo '<form method="POST" action="https://secure.nochex.com" name="form1" id="frm1">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="'.$rowsettings['nochex'].'">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'.$rowsettings['goldmemberfee'].'">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="'.$_SESSION['SellerID'].'">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="description" value="Gold Member Update for '.$_SESSION['BusinessEmail'].'">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="test_transaction" value="100">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="test_success_url" value= "successurl">';
    echo '<input type='hidden' name='success_url' value='".$rowsettings['url']."/goldmember.php?ncid=".$_SESSION['SellerID']."'>';
    echo '<input type='hidden' name='cancel_url' value='".$rowsettings['url']."/fail.php'>';
    echo '</form>';
```

Comment: yes but i want do this things in testing mode so i have to change the form action??

Comment: The "test_transaction" input sets the payment into test mode. Changing the form's action uses the new Payments Page system, rather than the older Checkout system, which requires different variables to the ones you have.